# sed regex with alternative on Solaris doesn't work

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed, solaris

Currently I'm trying to use sed with regex on Solaris but it doesn't work. 
I need to show only lines matching to my regex.

```
sed -n -E '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$|^a_[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/p'
```

input file:

```
grtad
a_pitr
_aupa
a__as
baman
12353
ai345
ki_ag
-MXx2
!!!23
+_)@*
```

I want to show only lines matching to above regex:

```
grtad
a_pitr
baman
12353
ai345
```

Is there another way to use alternative? Is it possible in perl?
Thanks for any solutions.

Comment: since patterns are mutually exclusive you can write: `sed -n -e '/^a_[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/p;/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/p;'` or `sed -n -e '/^a_[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/p;' -e '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/p;'`. Note that if you only need to filter, you can also use grep.

Comment: `sed -n -E '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$|^a_[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/p'` works for me on GNU sed, how exactly is it failing for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Perl

```
perl -ne 'print if /^(a_)?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/' input.txt
```

The `(a_)?` matches `a_` one-or-zero times, so optionally. It may or may not be there.

The `(a_)` also *captures* the match, what is not needed. So you can use `(?:a_)?` instead.  The `?:` makes `()` only group what is inside (so `?` applies to the whole thing), but not remember it.

Answer (score 1):

with `grep`

```
$ grep -xiE '(a_)?[a-z0-9]*' ip.txt
grtad
a_pitr
baman
12353
ai345
```

- `-x` match whole line
- `-i` ignore case
- `-E` extended regex, if not available, use `grep -xi '\(a_\)\?[a-z0-9]*'`
- `(a_)?` zero or one time match `a_`
- `[a-z0-9]*` zero or more alphabets or numbers

With `sed`

```
sed -nE '/^(a_)?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/p' ip.txt
```

or, with GNU `sed`

```
sed -nE '/^(a_)?[a-z0-9]*$/Ip' ip.txt
```